# Java 2d array negative number program

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d

this is what I am supposed to do:

"Write a code segment that searches a two-dimensional array for a negative integer. The loop should terminate at the first instance of a negative integer in the array, and the variables row and col should be set to its position. Otherwise, if there are no negative integers in the array, the variables row and col should equal the number of rows and columns in the array (we assume that each row has the same number of columns)."

So far this is what I have:

```
int[][] newArray = {{1, 2, 4, -7, 1}, {6, 4, -5, 2, 1}};

for(int row = 0; row < newArray.length; row++){
for (int col = 0; col < newArray[row].length; col++){
if (newArray[row][col] < 0){
//Number is negative

}
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How I can complete the assigned task...

Comment: If you question is how to solve this further, you are on the right track. Just break in that if statement and your problem should be over :)

Comment: @Gautham, I out the break statement in the "//Number is negative" section. However it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the outer loop as well, when the condition is met and you break out of the inner loop.

```
Boolean breaking = false;
for(int row = 0; row < newArray.length; row++){
for (int col = 0; col < newArray[row].length; col++){
if (newArray[row][col] < 0){
//Number is negative
   breaking = true; // Variable to break out of outer loop
   break;

}
}  //inner for loop scope ends here
if(breaking)
{
    break;
}

}
```